# Oracle SQL Developer + AWS Redshift : Can only view tables

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-redshift

I've gotten SQL Developer to be able to connect to my RedShift cluster but I can only see the tables. I can't see any of the views? Does anyone know if that's possible or if I should just be considering a different tool to work with Redshift?

If I use other tools (i.e. Aginity) I can see the views so I know it's not a DB permission thing, it must be a JDBC+SQL-Develop thing.

What tool do you use for RedShift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our redshift support is presented for a singular use case: copying/moving your data to the Oracle Autonomous Data Warehouse (ADW)

[image]

Can you connect and browse to a redshift instance? Yes. But that's not the desired use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Too bad to hear there's not more support in SQL Developer for Redshift. I've come to prefer it as my SQL tool over others out there.

Comment: @MichaelBlack appreciate your sentiment - but our first and primary goal is to provide support for Oracle db. we lack the resources and business motive to extend features to the competition